# How to write reusable functions that do logging

Tags: c, function, logging

I'm writing an application in C. I want to split everything up into various functions so that `main()` essentially just calls a few functions. Now it would be nice if these functions would be reusable, so that another application (for example an add-on) could use these. But these functions are logging what they are doing, because the main application is designed to interact with a user - the add-on programs don't neccessarily have to interact with users, and as such don't have to do logging.

So, programs that want to use some of my functions do not only depend on the functions itself, but also on the logging function. This is even worse if the program doesn't want to do any logging. How would I solve this?

Comment: Write about it in the readme file so that people reusing your code can grep the logging function calls out?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
#ifdef LOGGING
//logging code
#endif
```

Comment: Why do you think it's a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a parameter in each function to say whether you want it to do logging or not - useful if you think other programs may want to do logging for certain functions but not others.  Or have an initialisation function that turns logging on/off for the entire runtime.  Or, as @yi_H says, have a compile pragma to disable logging.

If these functions are truly generic, you would also presumably put them into a static or dynamic link library too.  Then having an 'initialisation' function to set the logging mode would make more logical sense from structural point of view.